# Why do these commands give different answers?

Tags: sorting

I'm using v12

```
list = {{0, 2}, {9, 0}, {4, 2}, {4, 8}, {1, 5}, {10, 8}, {7, 4}, {7, 9}, {9, 7}, {10, 9}};

SortBy[list, Norm]

> {{0, 2}, {9, 0}, {4, 2}, {4, 8}, {1, 5}, {10, 8}, {7, 4}, {7, 9}, {9, 7}, {10, 9}}

SortBy[list, N@*Norm]

> {{0, 2}, {4, 2}, {1, 5}, {7, 4}, {4, 8}, {9, 0}, {7, 9}, {9, 7}, {10, 8}, {10, 9}}
```

Comment: simpler input: `lst = {{9, 0}, {4, 2}}`?

Comment: [Sort >> Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sort.html): _**"Numeric expressions are sorted by structure as well as numerical value"**_. For example, compare `Sort@{9, 2 Sqrt[5]}` and `Sort@N@{9, 2 Sqrt[5]}` (similarly `Order @@ {9, 2 Sqrt[5]}` versus
`Order@@N@{9, 2 Sqrt[5]}`)

Answer (score 6):

From the Scope section of [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html)

Sort a list of vectors by their norm:

```
vectors = {{1/2, 1/3}, {1/4, 1/5}, {1/6, 1/7}};
SortBy[vectors, Norm]
Norm /@ %
```

> {{1/2, 1/3}, {1/4, 1/5}, {1/6, 1/7}}
>
> {Sqrt[13]/6, Sqrt[41]/20, Sqrt[85]/42}

Their norms are sorted following canonical order, but not numerical order:

```
OrderedQ[%]
N[%%]
```

> True
>
> {0.600925, 0.320156, 0.219513}

Explicitly request sorting of norms by numerical order:

```
SortBy[vectors, Norm, NumericalOrder]
N[Norm /@ %]
```

> {{1/6, 1/7}, {1/4, 1/5}, {1/2, 1/3}}
>
> {0.219513, 0.320156, 0.600925}